# Excel: Adding up values in only certain rows

Tags: excel, date, data-extraction

In sheet 1: In column A I have dates. In column B I have currency values. In sheet 2, how do I find the sum of the currency values in sheet 1 that correspond only with certain specified one-week date ranges?

Answer (score 2):

use `SUMIFS()` you can even use `<` and `>` for sumifs, such as:

`=SUMIFS(B:B;A:A;"<" & dateval1;A:A;">=" & dateval2)`

Comment: is there anything still not working correctly for this specific issue?